# How to create an onclick event handler for MainNavBar from the SpiffyUI framework

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that my navigation menu, when clicked, will open appropriate panels within my GWT page.

Here's a part of my code:

```
@Override
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    MainNavBar nb = new MainNavbar();
    NavItem i = new NavItem("1", "TestNavItem");
    nb.add(i);
    i = new NavItem("2", "TestNavItem2");
    nb.add(i);
}
```

So when I run the project, I see that I have a menu on the test site:

[image]

So my question is, how can I have an event handler such that when either one of those are clicked, the panel to the right will be changed to something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create an actionListener class,

```
public class listen implements actionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         if(e.getSource() == ObjectName){
              // Your code goes here....
         }
     }
}
```

then create an object of this class e.g

```
listen listener = new listen();
YourObjectName.addActionListener(listener);
```

Don't forget to make the imports, hope this helps...